# Error con synfony : Failed opening required autoload_real

Tags: php, php5, symfony2, symfony3

Estimados tengo este error en symfony y no me deja levantar mi proyecto:

```
c> php bin/console server:start --docroot=html

PHP Warning:  require(F:\xampp\htdocs\guiame-positiva\vendor\composer/../symfony/phpunit-bridge/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\xampp\htdocs\guiame-positiva\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

Warning: require(F:\xampp\htdocs\guiame-positiva\vendor\composer/../symfony/phpunit-bridge/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\xampp\htdocs\guiame-positiva\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'F:\xampp\htdocs\guiame-positiva\vendor\composer/../symfony/phpunit-bridge/bootstrap.php' (include_path='F:\xampp\php\PEAR') in F:\xampp\htdocs\guiame-positiva\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'F:\xampp\htdocs\guiame-positiva\vendor\composer/../symfony/phpunit-bridge/bootstrap.php' (include_path='F:\xampp\php\PEAR') in F:\xampp\htdocs\guiame-positiva\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
```

Es normal no tener el archivo composer.json? Quiero saber si es que mi proyecto esta incompleto.

Comment: has hecho el composer install?

Comment: si y me muestra un error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "FOSUserBundle" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
`

Comment: entonces ya no es el error de arriba? en que momento te muestra ese error?

Comment: Cuando hago `composer install` o cuando quiero ejecutar el proyecto `php bin/console server:start --docroot=html`

Comment: Se puede autogenerar el archivo composer.json? es decir que mi proyecto no lo tiene, en ves de copiarlo de realizar update. Existe algun codigo para crear automaticamente el archivo composer.json?

Comment: te lo crea el composer install

Comment: No, cuando ejecuto ese comando me pide que yo mismo cree el archivo y cuando lo creo vacio me muestra un error de caracteres referido al archivo .json vacio

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#init

Comment: Bien, excelente... pero me muestra este error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in F:\xampp\htdocs\guiame-positiva\app\autoload.php:11`